# Encase forensics .dd

Tags: computer-forensics, encase

I used Mandiant Intelligent Response to acquire a disk image of a window 7 computer. After it finished it gave me a .dd file. I have been trying to used Encase to analyse the file but when I add the evidence it does not give me the full file directory. Is the there a specific way I am supposed to add the evidence, or does encase not work with .dd files?

Comment: First, EnCase does work with .dd files and with Version 6 or 7, you just add it by using the "Add Raw image" selection which I am assuming you already did. No, you do not need to "process it first" via "process evidence" to view the file structure. As far as your issue, the .dd image could of been corrupted however that is probably not the case. I am not sure what you mean by "it does not give me the full file directory". Are you unable to pull down the full directory structure within the EnCase tree pane? Which OS are we talking about, what file system type? Let us know if you were able to ge

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old question. We're you able to resolve it?

As [labgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389925/labgeek) mentioned in their comment, add it as a raw image via the "Add Evidence" menu. For me, in EnCase 8, dragging in the dd image brought up the "Add Raw Image" dialog box automatically.

The only additional comment I have is that, in the "Add Raw Image" dialog, you might try specifying that it is a volume and selecting NTFS (since you got it from a Windows 7 box).

Answer (score 0):

Encase can works with dd files but you may process the evidence before list the directory structure. After adding the dd file as an encase evidence you have to process it from the encase menu.